# Stacked Histograms in R

Tags: r, histogram

![Y Axis: Frequency, X axis: Ratio][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmg3i.png

Can anyone help me with a suitable syntax to create this kind of a histogram in R? The input data will be the Ratio corresponding to a person and his/her age range. Sample:

Age            Ratio
(15-19)          0.97
(65-69)          1.2084
(50-64)          1.3049

and so on.

I'm not sure what these are called, could you mention the name of this kind of histogram as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have the best luck with the 'ggplot2' package, and the chart you're looking for is a "stacked bar chart" and not a histogram.

**Setup**: Create some sample data.

```
data <- data.frame(age=sample(c("15-19", "20-24", "25-29","30-34"),100,rep=TRUE), ratio=rnorm(100,mean=1,sd=0.3))
```

**Plot it**: We can just use the 'qplot' function here.

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(ratio, data=data, geom="bar", fill=age, binwidth=0.1)
```

Here, we tell the 'qplot' function to use the [ratio] data from our [data] data frame and to plot it in a bar chart geometry.  The data should be split and colored by the [age] (`fill=age`), and each bar should be 0.1 wide.  You should be able to adjust this to your needs.